# jsRender, data have to be in JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jsrender

I have a table that has a button on each TR that fires a jquery dialog, and i need to populate the dialog with the TD values of that TR #id

So i accomplished this by the following:

```
trid = $( this ).parents( 'tr' ).attr( "id" );
$('#'+trid+' td').each(function() {
        $("#bdcontent").append("<li>"+$(this).html()+"</li>");
    });
```

I use jsrender on multiple other parts of the same site, and didnt know how you could or should use jsRender in this respect

I suppose doing the following would get the job done, provided i knew the syntax to pass to teh template:

```
 <script id="billDialogTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>{{=???}}</li>
 </script>
 ...

$('#'+trid+' td').each(function() {
        $("#bdcontent").append( $("#billDialogTemplate").render( $(this) ));
    });
```

but wanted to see if there was a cleaner/better way, if i should not consider jsrender templating for this type of action, or even if jsrender could accept data that was not in JSON format, or how i could build a json array from the TD values then pass to jsrender

Comment: try use `{{html:#data}}`, this will show you the entire raw content that was passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you want only to pass the contents, you can access the contents with the `#data` special keyword

but why are you using jsRender for this simple task? if you only want to pass the content of your `<td>` why not

```
$("#bdcontent").append("<li>" + $(this) + "</td>");
```

if this is just an example and you have a complex template, you need to use `#data` to access the raw information that was passed into your template

```
<script id="billDialogTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>{{:#data}}</li>
</script>
```